# Get access_token from Azure AD in Cordova-app

Tags: javascript, cordova, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I have an Cordova-app (MobileFirst) in which I need to implement authentication with Azure AD.

Since Cordova-apps doesn't have a "url", I'm using the inAppBrowser-trick, which basically is query for the authorization code -> opens up inAppBrowser -> type in username and password on the SSO-screen -> close the browser window -> use the code that the browser got in return, then query for access token with a HTTP POST.

This works, kind of.

When I press my "Login"-button, it opens the inAppBrowser, shows the AD SSO-screen, and I can type username and password. Then I get the auth-code, which I then use to query the accesstoken. The problem is that it always complain about 
invalid grant with error: AADSTS70000: Authentication failed. Authorization Code is not valid / malformed.

For testing, I implemented login with Google OAuth2, which uses the same flow, and that works fine, I get the access_token when using Google.

At this point, I'm not sure if it is the configuration on Azure, or something in the app that is the problem.
I suspect it's the reply url (https://localhost/), but then I shouldn't have gotten a auth code in the first place (I think).

I can provide code if needed, but unsure what is relevant.

Any help?

TL;DR

Getting access token with auth code not working with Azure, but works with Google OAuth2, and they both use almost the same flow and code.

Answer (score -1):

We are working on a Cordova plugin for azure AD. We will release it soon, please keep an eye on blogs.technet.com/ad for announcements.